# Data tables loads all data(total records even after pagination) when i open ngdialog in angular material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables, angularjs-material

I am using Angular Datatables along with ngMaterial trying to build a CRUD app in which I can edit and delete records,
So what I have done is when I click on edit button it opens a model(Which is a dialog in ngMatrial along with data of that row) But when I am clicking on edit button dialog is opening but with this my data tables loads full data, not 10 or 25 records as per pagination.

Here is my Code :

> Controller

```
$scope.EditUser = function(ev,id) {
                $mdDialog.show({
                    templateUrl: 'EditModel.html', //Edit modal
                    parent: angular.element(document.body),
                    targetEvent: ev,
                    clickOutsideToClose:true,
                    scope:$scope,
                    preserveScope: true,
                    controller: 'Homecontroller'
                  });
                $http({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: 'getUser.php', //getting data with repect to id 
                  data: {id:id}
                }).then(function(res) {
                    var res = res.data[0];
                    $scope.editName = res.name;
                    $scope.editAge = res.age;
                    $scope.editLocation = res.location;
                  });
            };
```

> HTML [n.id is the id of that row I am getting from ngrepeat]

```
 <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" id={{n.id}} ng-click="EditUser($event,n.id)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                </button>
```